# Using an arbitrary maximum in range()

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Is there a way in Python to iterate over every integer until something happens? Right now I tend to do one of the following:

```
for i in range(999999999):
   ...
   if something:
       break
```

or

```
i = 0
status = True
while status:
    ...
    if something:
        status = False
    i += 1
```

Both of these methods work for what I'm doing, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `itertools.count`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for x in itertools.count():
...     print x
...     if x > 10: break
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```